# Non-Linear Questionnaires in Wordpress

Tags: plugin-recommendation, pagination, forms, export

I want to make the following happen in Wordpress

1. People answer questions in paginated or single page form.
2. Each next set of options is dependent on the option the user selects preiviously
3. At the end, the user is directed to a page which is a common ending for all questionnaire trees.
4. All this questionnaire options can be viewed/exported

**Question:** How can this be done? or if there is a plugin available for a similar purpose?  If not wordpress, is there another CMS that offers this?

Comment: Very good idea, make it happen

Comment: ... More seriously, I could not find a single question mark in your question. Be specific. Show you tried to find some solutions.

Comment: apart from the humour, I was short on time earlier, just managed to slip in the text, added the question now. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is capable of doing exactly what you are after
http://www.gravityforms.com/

Comment: Geez, this looks like it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any plugin that does what you want, but you could implement your logic in the index.php or page.php, and simply include templates based on the contents of `$_POST`. The only thing to remember is to pass the values received at the subsequent stages of the form to the next stage (you can generate `<input type="hidden">` fields).

Alternatively, you may contain the entire form with all its branches in one template, and switch the branches on and off with javascript. jQuery makes it very easy to watch the form contents change, and to hide and show relevant parts of the form. This solution would enable you to use an existing form-building plugin, such as this powerful one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/